# bundleconfig.json configured, but bundles not being created in ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, bundling-and-minification

Using the [Bundle and minify static assets in ASP.NET Core page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification?view=aspnetcore-3.1) as a guide, I've created a bundleconfig.json in my project root and set it up to create the css and script bundles I want to create. The page seems to imply that while 3rd party tools like Gulp or Grunt can be used, they are not required for basic purposes and I should be able to "Build the application" and then find the bundled .min files created, but they are not there after I build. I tried simplifying my config to just bundle two CSS files together but it still doesn't create the output file. Here are my bundleconfig.json contents:

```
[
    {
        "outputFileName": "wwwroot/css/tlgsso.min.css",
        "inputFiles": [
            "wwwroot/css/application.css",
            "wwwroot/css/site.css"
        ]
    }
]
```

I have been assuming this is meant to work simply by having a file named "bundleconfig.json" in the root.  As has frequently been the case, all I can find is information on ASP.NET Core 1-2.0. Am I missing something needed to trigger the bundling & minification?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I needed to install the [BundlerMinifier.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BundlerMinifier.Core) NuGet package. Then it worked.

Comment: You need also to install Gulp if you wish to use modification with CI. Rightclick bundleconfig.json, "Bundling & Minify", and "Convert to Gulp". It will add packet.json and gulpfile.js. Need to run also "npm i"